# Bot Framework .dialog file and CodeAction

Tags: botframework, declarative, custom-code

Is it possible to add a `CodeAction` to the declarative .dialog file somehow? Or what is the current way of calling custom code from a trigger action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to use code actions with declarative dialogs. You'll have export the runtime and follow these instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/composer/how-to-add-custom-action

Comment: Thanks. Is there any chance in the future it will be available?

Comment: I seriously doubt it. How could you put the code in a JSON file?